# Trigger HP Webinspect from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Does anyone have experience they could share in trying to automate/trigger HP Webinspect security scans from Jenkins (assuming jenkins has a pipeline to deploy the code to a container, such as tomcat, and start tomcat with a hosturl to give to webinspect)?

Searching google seems to be lite on the subject, and the one jenkins plugin around webinspect seems to focus on uploading to SCA rather than the scan itself (maybe I'm wrong).

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried batch commands to trigger a scan from Jenkins, but it ends up showing this error.
"This tool is not licensed for use by WebInspect."
But when I use the same command through cmd, it triggers a scan.

Command which I used - wi.exe -u "http://demo.testfire.net/bank/login.aspx" -ps 1 -s "C:\Programdata\HP\HP WebInspect\Settings\Default.xml" -am "C:\Program Files\HP\HP WebInspect\Samples\WebMacros\zero_login.webmacro" -ep ".\test1.fpr"

Answer (score 0):

I never used HP Webinspect with Jenkins, but here is another alternative that you use with Jenkins, through a plugin. Read about it here: https://blog.probely.com/how-to-configure-jenkins-to-integrate-security-into-ci-cd-2b340728de56

You scan start a scan from Jenkins both in a freestyle and pipeline project.

full disclosure: i'm highly affiliated with Probely, i'm the CTO :)